# css element.style display:none; being recognized instead of actual CSS

Tags: css

I am having an issue with an li tag being written as `element.style { display:none; }` when I have an id or div attached to it. For example:

```
<ul id="nav>
    <li class="another">this</li>
</ul>
```

In this instance I could either write `ul#nav {}` or `#nav li{}` or `.another{}` which I could then put inside anyone of those a `display:inline-block;` . The problem is I do that, but the web site still recognizes is as `element.style {display:none;}` for some reason and I can't figure out why the CSS won't work. I've even tried to do

```
<li style="display:block;"></li>
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: if your css file is a separate one, then put the reference to it under all the external and internal css references.

Comment: all my CSS files are referenced

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle?

Comment: are you seeing this element.style in firebug or some other inspect tool? if so then it is probably added by js and of course that will overwrite your css since it is inline. Even when you try to put inline css, the js will overwrite that as well

Comment: yeah seeing it in firebug

Answer (score 3):

When inspecting in Chrome, `element.style` means that it's an inline style, ie.

```
<li style="display:none;"></li>
```

Since the original markup obviously doesn't contain it as you've tried to override it, it is likely being set by JavaScript.

I recommend looking to see if you can find where it is being set in your JS, if that fails or you can't change it, you can always use the less recommended approach and flag your style as `!important` which will override inline styles.

```
#nav li {
    display:block!important;
}
```

Comment: yeah !important works but I hate using it. I guess I'll have to search through the JS to see if it is being referenced there. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, only use `!important` if you absolutely have to :)